# Only for a few people

Tags: riddle, word

I posted this riddle for an unforeseen.

Clue 1:

> Since 1935...

Clue 2:

> An uncle always in

Clue 3:

> Some references about the invisible hand

Clue 4:

> Only one will get it...

Clue 5:

> But luck is the real protagonist

**Who am I?**

Comment: Something to do with the great depression, the economy or ecomomic theory perhaps?

Comment: Well, it's not that history-related, it's more friendly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This riddle describes the

> **Monopoly** board game.

Clue 1: Since 1935...

> In 1935 Monopoly was sold by Parker Brothers and a patent issued to Charles Darrow.  The Landlord's Game was similar and created by Lizzie Magie in 1903.

Clue 2: An uncle always in

> Rich Uncle Pennybags is the mascot.

Clue 3: Some references about the invisible hand

> A reference to Adam Smith's phrase that describe benefits of individual self-interested actions in a free market economy, and is at odds with a monopoly.

Clue 4: Only one will get it...

> In a monopoly [Greek: single sell] one party has exclusive control over a product or service.

Clue 5: But luck is the real protagonist

> Rolling dice and drawing cards means Monopoly is a game of luck as well as skill.

Title: Only for a few people

> The game of Monopoly is for two to eight players.

Comment: Really, but really congratulations! The explanations are completely correct and they indicate you're a very accultured man (as your reputation demonstrates). This answer is the right one

Answer (score 1):

Could you be the...

> **one dollar bill**...

> whose backside was designed in **1935**

> Uncle : this one I don't have... May the "uncle" be G. Washington?

> **THe invisible hand** : one someone says that the Eye of Providence is also a symbol of **freemasonry**.

> **One will get it** : **one dollar**

> Luck is the real protagonist: another one I don't get... maybe part of an american expression ?

> And the title  "**only for a few people**" : because it's only for americans?

Comment: That's an interesting answer, despite some points are not enough clarified, it shows some concepts that most people does not know... however I'm sorry to say that this is not the answer I was looking for. Keep trying, it's not that far after all

Comment: @xKobalt is it related to the book The Invisible Hand??

Comment: @Lakshay Sura, it's quite simple as reference: it's just about the concept